# how to identify process is in frozen state in python?

Tags: python, process

**How to identify process is in frozen state in python**

I am running python file on server on every mid night, Sometime its go into Frozen status. This is happens after 5 or 6 days?

Python script not take much memory or load during running, its takes 4 hrs if 120 documents for publish.

**Following Steps:**

1. Run Python script custom.py
2. After 1 hrs again run same python script when there is No same script in running.

If script is previous script is still in system then same script will not terminate.

But is process which running script goes into Froze or Zombie state, then next time script will not run because pervasion script still in system.

Comment: You can use a cron job, it will restart the program

Comment: yes, I am running by cron tab, but script goes into frozen state.

Comment: do you have prints on your script?

Comment: what do you mean by 'frozen state'?

Comment: means process hang or go into zombie state(this happens at mid night 00:30), but after 2 hrs we run script again and this time script Publish all documents.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a script to be killed by timeout and you're on UNIX, you can use SIGALRM: [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call)

If you want to prevent several copies of the same script to be launched, there are several solutions. The simplest one is `ps aux | grep`. If it's not enough you may use filelock package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock/
But from my experience it's still not stable. The best solution is to use sys-v ipc semaphores http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/. You may set `undo` flag to remove semaphore lock once the process terminates.